# Change inner html on key press javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, contenteditable, innerhtml, onkeypress

I have following code

```js
function kpress(){
  document.getElementById("editable").innerHTML = document.getElementById("editable").innerHTML.replace("this","that");
}
```

```html
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true" style="width:100px;height:100px" onkeypress="kpress()"></div>
```

Problem is I don't want to replace the old innerHTML with the innerHTML with replace() method instead I want something like this

```
document.getElementById("editable").innerHTML.replace("this", "that");
```

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("editable").innerHTML = document.getElementById("editable").innerHTML.replace("this", "that");
```

Comment: Do you have to use native JavaScript because jQuery has a .text() function that does what your asking pretty easy.

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript replace text in the html body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558613/javascript-replace-text-in-the-html-body)

Comment: @SergeyDenisov The original replace I want to implement is like this
'innerHTML.replace(RegularExpression,"<span>$1<span>");'
Where "RegularExpression" is a regular expression which mathes with a number and "$1" is the substring which matched with regular expression

Comment: Hey EMM, don't forget to choose an answer when your problem has been solved! If it hasn't been solved, please update your question!

Answer (score 1):

innerHTML either gets or sets the HTML for an element. When using `innerHTML` like this: `innerHTML.replace("this","test")` you are actually getting the HTML in the form of a string and applying the replace method to the string.  When using `innerHTML` in the context of `Element.innerHTML =` you are setting the value of the HTML.  [See here for reference.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)

Here's a clean way to implement what you want with JavaScript : [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Lak49k85/1/)

```js
document.getElementById("editable").onkeypress = function (){
    this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace("this","that");
}
```

```css
#editable {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border:1px #ccc solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="editable" contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Comment: Nice! You could make it even cleaner as `this.innerHTML = this.innerHTML.replace("this","that");` and save yourself that extra DOM crawl.

Answer (score 1):

When using plain javascript you have to assign something to the innerHTML in order to change it.

The native replace method returns a string, **but doesn't modify the DOM.**

You can make it a bit shorter, but can't avoid the steps 1) get the element 2) change it's value.

```
var ed = document.getElementByID("editable");
ed.innerHTML = ed.innerHTML.replace("this","that");
```

Answer (score 0):

jQuery makes this way easier, and unfortunately I don't know of a way to replace text in a string without having to set that string again. I think the most you can do is make your code more readable and only do the element lookup once:

```
var editableElement = document.getElementById("editable");
editableElement.innerHTML = editableElement.innerHTML.replace("this", "that");
```