# How to replace all occurrences of a string in a HTML page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, replace

I know this question may be asked before but I did not find the correct answer that works.

I tried this code

```
$('body *').each(function(k,v){$(v).text($(v).text().replace("Hazem","mizzo"))});
```

but the page crashes, I don't know why.

I'm prefer the code to be in pure javascript not jQuery.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript replace text in the html body](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558613/javascript-replace-text-in-the-html-body)

Comment: @ManasovDaniel: That's a duplicate indeed, but gives a terrible solution.

Comment: Add a `<span class="name-to-replace">Hazem</span>` to all the instances where you have the string you want to replace. Then, just use something analogous to `$(".name-to-replace")` (or `document.getElementsByClassName("name-to-replace")` as your selector.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should walk the DOM, find text nodes, and replace the found text in each.

Here's a simple example. You can make `walkText()` more generic by passing a callback that does the replacement.

```js
function walkText(node) {
  if (node.nodeType == 3) {
    node.data = node.data.replace(/foo/g, "bar");
  }
  if (node.nodeType == 1 && node.nodeName != "SCRIPT") {
    for (var i = 0; i < node.childNodes.length; i++) {
      walkText(node.childNodes[i]);
    }
  }
}
walkText(document.body);
```

```html
foo <b>foo</b> foo
```