# Wrapping poorly formed html in div tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I know this sounds like a bad move and I should just edit the html, however I really have no choice. I am working with a template for a rescue group and have no access to the html and just limited access to styles. To access the javascript I am hacking the tinymce plugin to inject scripts.

The html is pretty poorly formed and for the most part I can go in a hack around it, but I have found myself in the situation where I need to put a div around some of the html so I can give it a class and style them. However there is very little to go by.

The repeating html looks like this. This is the html I need wrapped in a div.

```
<b>Text</b>
<br>
"Some Text here annoyingly placed outside a tag."
<br>
"More text outside a tag."
<br>
"Title outside of tag"
<a>Link</a>
<br>
<br>
"More text and then a link"
<a>Link</a>
<br>
<br>
<a>Ending Link</a>
<hr>
```

The full html is in this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3h85vhcx/ There are very few id's and very little to work with.

Is there anyway to wrap this in a div tag using jquery/javascript?

Comment: Yes there is, but question is, how you get this HTML? Is it in variable, or is it object, or maybe you see it in page, etc..

Comment: The html is the mark up on the page. I would have to grab elements like $('hr').

Comment: Yes you can, using [`.wrapAll`](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/) but how do you get this html?

Comment: It's terrible. Post the full html so we could see how to get this

Comment: @MoshFeu I don't know what you mean? I am working after the page renders in the dom ready. If you would like the full page, I'm trying to edit this http://cats-caninc.rescuegroups.org/info/events

Comment: @MoshFeu It's all like that, there is one id at the top of the page and that's it. That's why this has me so frustrated it's very bad mark up.

Comment: BUT in your posted link, they use a table, is that this table you want to wrap inside a div or each TDs content or what??? It is still unclear how do you get this HTML...

Comment: @A.Wolff I want to wrap the html posted above in a div. That html repeats so I would like to add a class to them to better style it. Someone asked for the full html so I put it in the jsFiddle.

Comment: @zazvorniki But wraping TR element inside a DIV would result in invalid HTML markup (jsfiddle code). Why don't you just add a class to TR elements??? If you want to wrap TD content instead, then use `$('td').contents().wrapAll('<div class="myClass"/>');`

Comment: Not easy. Maybe you can try to play with the `name` attribute of the `a` tag: `$('a[name^=Event]')` and with the `nextUntil()` jquery function: http://jqapi.com/#p=nextUntil

Comment: @A.Wolff I don't really care if it's valid or not just as long as it works. There is already a ton of invalid code on this site. I need to wrap this specific text posted above not the tr that encompasses the entire page. All the code is in the one td as well.

Comment: @ThomasMauduit-Blin I'll give it a shot. I'm up for anything that does not involve me replacing the whole body haha

Comment: @zazvorniki So can you try `$('#PageHeader').closest('td').contents().wrapAll('<div class="myClass"/>');`  Is it what you are looking for???

Comment: @A.Wolff No, not at all. I wish it was that easy. The html that I posted above repeats and I need to wrap that specific html into a div. It starts with the b and ends with the hr.

Comment: @zazvorniki So i understand it like this: `$('b').each(function(){
   $(this).nextUntil('hr + *').addBack().wrapAll('<div class="myClass" />')
});`  But still not sure it is what you are expecting...   https://jsfiddle.net/3h85vhcx/1/

Answer (score 0):

It's not very clear.
But if I've understood a bit, you could get the body html as a string,
work on it adding what you need with a series of operations with substrings.
And then replace the body html with the new one.

But is it a client-side thing right?

Comment: Yes it is client side,  that is why I tagged javascript and html in my question. I was hoping there was a better way then just replacing the whole body after the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Not best solution, but you can try this:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('<a name=Event' '<div><a name=Event');
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('event.<br><br>', 'event.<br><br></div>');
```

It's far from best solution, but finding patterns and then replacing them will be a good start.

This stack helped me: **[Replace words in the body text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558613/javascript-replace-text-in-the-html-body)**

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing this in small spurts, but I was hoping with such a large page and many places that there would be a better way.

Comment: Well, you can count elements from top and create new objects and etc, but first step is to get elements in places for editing.

Comment: Problem is nothing is static so the next time someone changes it then it would be completely messed up. I'm starting to see this is a no win situation. haha

Comment: Just keep working and keep it basic. It's our job as developers to invent solutions...

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery function [`nextUntil`](http://jqapi.com/#p=nextUntil) associated with [`wrapAll`](http://jqapi.com/#p=wrapAll) can done that. According to your HTML, something like this could do the job:

```
$('hr').each(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('hr').wrapAll('<fieldset />')
});
```

Here is your jsfiddle updated: https://jsfiddle.net/5hudL6vk/

I wrapped the contents you want to match with a fieldset to be more obvious

Comment: It seems like there is an issue with the wrapAll because of the plain text mixed in there

Comment: @zazvorniki Hum yes...maybe the issue is with nextUntil that do not select plain text