# I want to replace one word from all page when website is loaded

Tags: javascript, replace, web, words, loaded

In my website, there have many page and content.
Now I want to replace one word from all page when website is loaded.

Comment: Refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558613/javascript-replace-text-in-the-html-body)

Answer (score 0):

```js
timer = setInterval(myFunction,100);
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("hello", "hi");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to replace "hello" with "hello" in the paragraph below:</p>

<p id="demo">Visit hello!</p>
```

Comment: Please give me a way, When website is loaded then function. Thanks