# change protocol of urls on webpage via javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Some of our urls on the pages are still in http and we cannot get this correct at the server side. Is there some javascript code to rewrite all urls with http:// to // or https://?

EDIT:

By testing with the anwser of T.J. Crowder I got all the "a href" to be replaced.

However I had a lot of different places with urls of images like:

```
    <header class="category_header init_bg_mobile" data-bg="//test.jpg" data-bg-md="http://test2.jpg" data-bg-xs-2x="http://test.jpg" >
```

So I made a mix of his anwser and [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558613/javascript-replace-text-in-the-html-body) anwser.

```
     <script>

       (function(){
      Array.prototype.forEach.call(

         document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('http://',       '//');

     )();

     </script>
```

This does the trick for now.

A side note, I don't think this is good practice since it changes every single place "http://" is on the page, which can also rewrite it if it is intented in the text. However it does the trick for now.

Comment: Are they in links?

Comment: And what have you tried? If they're in links, and you're using jQuery, this is trivial. (Even if they aren't in links, it's really straightforward.)

Comment: well the problem is that jquery sometimes is the url that has http and therefor isn't loaded

Comment: So again: Are they in links (`<a href="..."`)? Or is it also `script` and `link rel="stylesheet"`? This question is really very, very vague.

Comment: So you want to load site with https when some one click url with http only ?

Comment: Yes some urls of images,javascript, css or links are http instead of https

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you know, the correct fix here is to fix those links server-side, ideally by removing the scheme entirely, to create *scheme-relative* URLs like this:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But you've said you can't do that.

So:

- You can readily find all `a` elements via `document.querySelectorAll`.
- You can easily loop through the result.
- ...and get their `href` via `getAttribute` (or the resolved URL via the `href` property)
- ...and update it if necessary (via `setAttribute` or the `href` property).
- Similarly, `script` and `link rel="stylesheet"`.

Here's a simple example for links:

```
Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll("a[href]"),
    function(link) {
        if (link.href.startsWith("http://")) {
            link.href = "https://" + link.href.substring(7);
        }
    }
);
```

Ensure that's in a `script` tag at the end of `</body>` so that the elements exist as of when it runs.

Generalize as needed for `img` (the `src` property), `script` (the `src` property), `link[rel=stylesheet]` (the `href` property), ... (Each of those is a valid CSS selector which will work with `querySelectorAll`.)

Comment: Your solution seems to be the thing I want only it doesn't work for me. I updated my anwser  for what I tried.

Comment: @user3605780: Look at the answer above, and look at the code in your question. They're not at all the same. In the answer, I'm finding the **elements** that need fixing and fixing them individually. In your question's code, you're trying to do a mass replace on `document.body.innerHTML`. A) That's a very bad idea, it completely tears down the document and builds it up, and B) You'd need a regex with the `g` flag for it to work (but see [A]).