# Javascript - Find and replace specific text

Tags: javascript, html, string, replace

I would need to find and replace some text on my website (online store) using CS. Specifically, I need to find `,90` in price area and replace this with upper index `<sup>90</sup>`. At the moment the price is displayed as follows:

```
39,90 Kč,
```

i want to be displayed:

```
39<sup>90</sup> Kč
```

I tried it according to the instructions

```
document.body.innerHTML.replace
```

unfortunately without success.

Comment: Use `.replace(/,90/g, '<sup>90</sup>')`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace words in the body text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558613/replace-words-in-the-body-text)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple regular expression first to find all of the occurrences of  `,90` in the string:

```
/,90/g
```

And then you could use [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace it with the `<sup></sup>` tags:

```
str.replace(/,90/g, "<sup>90</sup>");
```

Demonstration:

```js
var str = "30,90 12,90 3,90";
str = str.replace(/,90/g, "<sup>90</sup>");
document.body.innerHTML = str;
```