# After finding a word in html body, replace it with another one

Tags: javascript

i have this code that finds a word in the entire body of a html page

```
var word = "active",
    queue = [document.body],
    curr
;
while (curr = queue.pop()) {
    if (!curr.textContent.match(word)) continue;
    for (var i = 0; i < curr.childNodes.length; ++i) {
        switch (curr.childNodes[i].nodeType) {
            case Node.TEXT_NODE : // 3
                if (curr.childNodes[i].textContent.match(word)) {
                    console.log("Found!");
                    console.log(curr);
                    // you might want to end your search here.
                    word.replace('active', 'test');
                }
                break;
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE : // 1
                queue.push(curr.childNodes[i]);
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

And what i'm trying to do is if active is found, replace it with something else but i have tried some ways and i wasnt able to do it. What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: `word.replace('active', 'test');` replaces the `active` found in variable `word` with `test` and returns (which you've discarded) the changed text ... i.e. that line of code does nothing useful ... you need to change the text inside `.textContent`

Comment: `curr.childNodes[i].textContent = curr.childNodes[i].textContent.replace(word, 'test');`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replace words in the body text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558613/replace-words-in-the-body-text)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would give the result you are looking for (I decided to skip of `'SCRIPT'` `nodeName`'s so you do not accidentally modify any code:

```js
let word = "active";
let queue = [document.body];
let curr;

while (curr = queue.pop()) {
  if (!curr.textContent.match(word) || curr.nodeName === 'SCRIPT') continue;
  for (var i = 0; i < curr.childNodes.length; ++i) {
    if (curr.childNodes[i].nodeName === 'SCRIPT') continue;
    switch (curr.childNodes[i].nodeType) {
      case Node.TEXT_NODE: // 3
        if (curr.childNodes[i].textContent.match(word)) {
          console.log("Found!", `'${curr.childNodes[i].textContent}'`);
          curr.childNodes[i].textContent = curr.childNodes[i].textContent.replace('active', 'test');
        }
        break;
      case Node.ELEMENT_NODE: // 1
        queue.push(curr.childNodes[i]);
        break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div>asdf</div>
<span>active</span>
<div>asdf</div>
```

Hope this helps,