# How do I remove only part of some text on a header using Jquery or HTML?

Tags: html, jquery, squarespace

I'm trying to remove the words "Posts In", but keep cookware.

```
  <header class="BlogList-filter"> 

  Posts in Cookware

<header/> =0
```

I've tried a number of different solutions. Including:

```
   $(".BlogList-filter").html("Cookware")
```

I don't like this because it doesn't change dynamically on other pages like "Bedding".

```
$(':contains("Posts In:")').each(function(){
$(this).html($(this).html().split("Posts In:").join(""));
});
```

This hides everything on the page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Replace words in the body text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5558613/replace-words-in-the-body-text) (just replace with empty string `''`)

Comment: In many cases, for Squarespace sites, this can be done with CSS alone. If you provide a link to the site/page in question or state what template you're using, that should be enough to offer a solution.