# How to determine if HTML text is using an icon font?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am making something similar to [this browser extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xkcd-substitutions/jkgogmboalmaijfgfhfepckdgjeopfhk) that substitutes certain phrases with silly equivalents throughout a webpage. I have read [replace words in the body text](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5558613/16458492) but one problem that every answer shares is that they also break icon fonts. To see what I mean, go to Google Font's [Material Icons demo page](https://fonts.google.com/icons) and edit the text content inside a `<span>` with an icon. I found [this recommendation by the W3C](https://www.w3.org/WAI/WCAG21/Techniques/aria/ARIA24) that font icons be identified with the ARIA `role="img"` attribute. But this depends on proper implementation by the developer which the demo page seems to lack.

I came up with the following kludge which appears to work for the pages I've tested it on. I would think that the probability of there existing an icon font without "icon" in its name is lower than that of developers setting the `role` attribute correctly, but clearly both approaches are very fragile and I am wondering if there is something more robust.

```js
window.getComputedStyle(node).getPropertyValue('font-family').toUpperCase().includes('ICON')
```

Comment: I mean, the _real_ solution is to only replace text where _you know_ it should be replaced, not just blindly for the whole page. Query-select all the elements that you, as developer, know should be found by a query selector match, and then replace their text, and you never run into the problem of accidentally messing with an icon font.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I wish I could, but I'm making something along the lines of [this XKCD substitutions extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xkcd-substitutions/jkgogmboalmaijfgfhfepckdgjeopfhk) whose whole point is to be run on the whole page.

Comment: Then you want to [put that detail in your post](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

This isn't 100% infallible, but one would sincerely hope that in any occurrence of an icon font, the element will have a `class` attribute and somewhere in that `class` attribute the letters `i`, `c`, `o` and `n` will be found consecutively and in that order.

In which case, for any `textNode` you can run the following check:

```
if ((myTextNode.parentNode.hasAttribute('class') === false) || (myTextNode.parentNode.className.includes('icon') === false)) {

  // REPLACE TEXT
}
```

But as you've already recognised, this does require the implementor actually using the word **icon** somewhere in the `className` of the element containing the `textNode`.