# Are any HTML attributes rendered as text by the browser besides alt text and <input> placeholder?

Tags: html

I am trying to find and replace **all** the text on a webpage with JavaScript. I am currently using a variation of the following code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50537862/16458492) which recursively processes every `Text` node in the document.

```js
function replaceInText(element, pattern, replacement) {
    for (let node of element.childNodes) {
        switch (node.nodeType) {
            case Node.ELEMENT_NODE:
                replaceInText(node, pattern, replacement);
                break;
            case Node.TEXT_NODE:
                node.textContent = node.textContent.replace(pattern, replacement);
                break;
            case Node.DOCUMENT_NODE:
                replaceInText(node, pattern, replacement);
        }
    }
}

replaceInText(document, /e/gi, '');
```

Once I tested it out, I discovered that there's an exception: the `placeholder` attribute of `<input>` and `<textarea>` elements. These are **not** `Text` nodes, but are still displayed as visible text by the browser and searchable with CTRL-F. Try running the above on the Stack Overflow homepage and see that the search bar is left out.

Now I'm wondering if there's any other attributes out there like this too. All I can currently think of is `value` for `<input>` and `<textarea>`, `alt` for `<img>` and `<area>`, and the global `title` attribute (tooltips), and I'm worried I'm missing some obscure attribute since I couldn't find a comprehensive list of this sort anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a while and I've discovered `value` for `input[type="button"]`and I will record my list so far below. I have marked the answer as community wiki so anybody who finds more can easily add them.

- `placeholder` for [`<input>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) and [`<textarea>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/textarea): placeholder text
- `value` for `<input>` and `<textarea>`: actual contents of field
- `value` for [`<input type="button">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/button): the text inside the button
- `alt` for [`<img>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img), [`<area>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/area), and [`<input type="image">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/image): alternative text for when images fails to load
- [`title`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/title) for anything: tooltip that displays on mouse hover